# cryptic message in secure logs

Tags: security, ssh

I'm seeing this message turning up frequently in my secure logs.

```
pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
```

However I have no idea what this means. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from pam, not from sshd directly. Basically someone tries to login to the box you're looking at, sends login name "root", but pam is configured to disallow any user below uid 1000 from connecting. (root normally uses uid 0)

Unless you really want to connect as root yourself, this is a good thing.